# Ajax call is not working

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, jsp, servlets

I am very new to ajax concept,I want to submit a form without refresh the page

**ajax**

```
function ajaxFunction() {
  if(xmlhttp) { 
   var txtname = document.getElementById("txtname");
    xmlhttp.open("POST","Listservlet",true);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange  = handleServerResponse;
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xmlhttp.send("txtname=" + txtname.value);
  }
}

function handleServerResponse() {
   if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
     if(xmlhttp.status == 200) {
       document.fname.message.innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
     }
     else {
        alert("Error during AJAX call. Please try again");
     }
   }
}
```

**JSP**

```
<form name="fname" action="Listservlet" method="post">
<input type="text" name="txtname" id="txtname" />
<input type="button" value="Submit"  onclick="ajaxFunction();" />
<div id="message"></div>
</form>
```

**servlet**

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
  String name = null;
  PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
  if(request.getParameter("txtname") != null) {
   name = request.getParameter("txtname");
  }
                else {
                       name = "";
                }
           out.println("You have successfully made Ajax Call:" + name);
 }
```

This ajax idea I got from google,  bt it is not working,
While clicking on the button,nothing it showing.
Please help me.

Comment: press **F12** go console. found any error logs?

Comment: You should provide browser + versions you're trying to make it work.

Comment: yea it showing error like  3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of undefined

Comment: Probably a cross browser issue. You should take a look at Mozilla docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/AJAX/Getting_Started There's a complete working example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace

```
 document.fname.message.innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
```

by

```
document.getElementById("message").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
```

Answer (score 1):

**General Steps to find out where goes wrong**:

use browser debugger to tell if ajax request was successfully sent;

debug your receiving Servlet, to tell if request was actually delivered to your Servlet;

use browser debugger to tell if the response text is desired one;

for your issue I think you need to 
change 
`document.fname.message.innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;` 
to 
`document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;`

**Also remember Close your ouputstream**